# Ruby DSL used across multiple <% %> tags or multiple lines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, block, erb, dsl

I am writing a helper DSL to make it easier to craft a nice menu ui within a view.  The view's erb is producing an error `undefined method 'safe_append=' for nil:NilClass` when I break the block across multiple erb tags but it works fine if I stick it in one tag.  I want to understand why -- it should work across multiple tags and is a lot more natural.

This doesn't work:

```rb
          <%= @menu.start do -%>
              <%= menu_item some_path_in_routesrb, 
                  title: "Dashboard", 
                  details: "12 New Updates", 
                  icon: "feather:home",
                  highlight: true 
              %>
              <%= menu_item next_path, 
                  title: "Magical stuff", 
                  details: "unicorn registry", 
                  icon: "fontawesome:rainbow",
                  highlight: true 
              %>
          <% end -%>
```

But this works:

```rb
          <%= @menu.start do 

                  menu_item "#", 
                  title: "Dashboard", 
                  details: "12 New Updates", 
                  icon: "fe:home",
                  first: true,
                  highlight: true 

                  menu_item organizations_path, 
                  title: "Organization", 
                  details: "33k Updates", 
                  icon: "fa:university"

          end -%>
```

The aforementioned `start` method for a menu looks like this

```rb
    def start(&block)
        if block_given?
            self.instance_eval(&block)
        else
            raise "menu expected a block!"
        end
    rescue => e
        @logger.ap e.message,   :error
        @logger.ap e.backtrace, :error
    ensure                
        if @menu_items.size > 0
            return content_tag(:div, content_tag(:ul, self.display, class: "menu-items"), class:"sidebar-menu")
        else 
            return "There is nothing to render here. Place an item in the menu"
        end
    end
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6):

I tried to find an example of what you are trying to do and found that the closest thing to it is the `form_for`.

Then I tried to find why would your way not work.

After tracing the execution of code, it seems that the block is trying to render itself assuming it is inside the `ActionView::Context` instance where it is going to find [Context#output_buffer](https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.0.0/ActionView/Context#output_buffer-instance_method) where it finds `nil` and can't call `safe_append` on it.

Now how to solve this problem.

You have to make sure that whatever you are trying to render in the view has all the context it needs to render itself which is what Rails does in the form_for

```
        <%= @menu.start do |m| -%>
          <% m.menu_item some_path_in_routesrb, 
              title: "Dashboard", 
              details: "12 New Updates", 
              icon: "feather:home",
              highlight: true 
          %>
          <% m.menu_item next_path, 
              title: "Magical stuff", 
              details: "unicorn registry", 
              icon: "fontawesome:rainbow",
              highlight: true 
          %>
      <% end -%>
```

And have this in the menu class

```
 def start(&block)
        if block_given?
            yield self
        else
            raise "menu expected a block!"
        end
    rescue => e
        @logger.ap e.message,   :error
        @logger.ap e.backtrace, :error
    ensure                
        if @menu_items.size > 0
            return content_tag(:div, content_tag(:ul, self.display, class: "menu-items"), class:"sidebar-menu")
        else 
            return "There is nothing to render here. Place an item in the menu"
        end
    end
```

Now the idea of having `eval_instance` can be done but won't be actually that clean IMHO as it means that you will try to mimic the same behaviour of ERB parsing.

Comment: it feels cleaner to me.  How would I get that to work.  Yes I traced through the same code and even had my tags write to @output_buffer.  This isn't terribly well documented unless I just didn't see it.  We are already in the block, there should be no reason to give the context.  Like this is how all non ERB DSLs are written right?

Comment: This really bothers me, if you can help me understand how to get it to work with instance_eval, I will happily award the bounty.

Comment: The point here is that you are trying to mimic a core ruby function which is not supposed to be overridden. That's why there is no documentation here.

Comment: In another universe where writing to @output_buffer does work. Would you have considered it cleaner this way?

Comment: Of course.  It is clear to not need to use an object that should exist in a scope. How can it possibly be proper for every other DSL but not within ERB?!! In some other DSL it would be called name or scope pollution. Otherwise what reall is the point of the block's scope?!!! We shouldn't need to yield back the object. Wd should be free to use instance_eval here within the block's scope. Even if you told me that this is less clean, well it isn't consistent to toss instance_eval out the window.

Comment: Can you please answer the OP if you know of a way to do it and feel so inclined? (Despite your feelings about it).  I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The block given to the `start` function is different when you receive a "erb template" vs "the list of method calls", on the case that works (method calls) this is what is being executed by the Ruby interpreter:

```rb
@menu.menu_item("#", 
               title: "Dashboard", 
               details: "12 New Updates", 
               icon: "fe:home",
               first: true,
               highlight: true)
@menu.menu_item(organizations_path, 
               title: "Organization", 
               details: "33k Updates", 
               icon: "fa:university")
```

Which is valid Ruby.

On the other case you must parse that template string before you attempt to call `instance_eval`. I do not have the correct implementation answer for you but I would suggest looking at how others do, for example, I know ERB allows for:

```rb
<% if @cost < 10 %>
  <b>Only <%= @cost %>!!!</b>
<% else %>
  Call for a price, today!
<% end %>
```

So I would look at the [source code](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/b6fd7b1bb741edfe08b9f9da4652b5e1d5d3a57a/lib/erb.rb).

The other library that I know that allows this form of construction is [liquid by shopify](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid):

```
<ul id="products">
  {% for product in products %}
    <li>
      <h2>{{ product.name }}</h2>
      Only {{ product.price | price }}

      {{ product.description | prettyprint | paragraph }}
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I would also take a look at how the for loop is implemented in this case by looking at the [source code](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/blob/1518d3f6f9cd1bcdc40b049b7e880a962d488e1c/lib/liquid/tags/for.rb).

Hope that helps you get to the final implementation of your DSL.

Answer (score 1):

When you build blocks with `<%= %>` this means it will print something, what has a similar output as doing `<% puts 'something' %>`. Since your `start` method is expecting a block and the return value of a `<%= %>` block is `nil`, the exception `undefined method 'safe_append=' for nil:NilClass` is giving you a hint of what to do.

Change your blocks to just execute the code, so that the returning values get passed into the `start` method block, like this:

```
<%= @menu.start do %>
  <% menu_item some_path_in_routesrb, 
    title: "Dashboard", 
    details: "12 New Updates", 
    icon: "feather:home",
    highlight: true 
  %>
  <% menu_item next_path, 
    title: "Magical stuff", 
    details: "unicorn registry", 
    icon: "fontawesome:rainbow",
    highlight: true 
  %>
<% end %>
```

Also, remove the minus sign in your tags, since it avoid line breaks after the expression.

Comment: So actually my menu_items merely add text to an array in parent object Menu and my Menu object renders all of its objects via ensure. Hmm.  I liked that architecture but will change it I guess

Comment: While what you wrote makes sense, I'm not sure this is it.  It literally never enters the code path of the block when I break it across mutiple <% tags, I can see that a block is there (it has a non nil value) but it has the exception on the start-do line itself.

Comment: It's really bothering me.  It works find if not multiple erb tags.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `-` after the `do/end` declaration? The `<% -%>` is used to avoid line breaks after the declaration

Comment: Yeah, doesn't seem to matter.  This thing is driving me nuts.  It's like only looking at the start tag and not considering anything else if broken across multiple tags. but in one, perfect. I've even rewrote it so that menu_items returned rendered content instead of just enqueuing and being rendered by menu.start's ensure -- didn't matter.